# NSPredicate For Nested Relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm have trouble formatting a predicate to find a nested relationship in core data.  I've come across some very similar questions/comments that I had hoped would help me find the correct solution - but I'm still stuck.

[image]

I'm trying to create a fetch request to search for all instances of Foo that are related to a specific instance of Gadget.

I first attempted using a predicate on a fetchRequest for the Foo entity:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY bar.widgets.gadget == %@", myGadget]
```

but this fetch request returns 0 results.  I'm assuming its because of the nested to-many relationship.

I think I need to use a subquery, which I've never had to use before.  After much research and reading, I tried

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(bar.widgets, $w, ANY $w.gadget == %@).@count > 0", myGadget]
```

And I receive the error

> SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t2.ZGADGET'

So, am I correct in thinking I need a subquery for this scenario, and if so how do I correctly format it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "bar.widgets.gadget" in the first predicate? If that does not work, try the SUBQUERY without ANY ("gadget" is a to-one relationship).

Comment: Does it need to be a predicate or is navigating the relationships using KVC an acceptable alternative?

Comment: I'm with @Wain, if you already have a Gadget, just traverse the relationships to find all the Foos.

Comment: Martin, yes it should be bar.widgets.gadget - that was a typo in the question, that is the predicate I attempted.

Comment: I actually am traversing through the relationships to find the objects I need using [myGadget  valueForKeyPath:@"widgets.bars.@distinctUnionOfSets.foo"].  I resorted to that after being unable to come up with a predicate to fetch against.  I'm not sure of the performance difference between the two approaches, but I'm interested to find a predicate that works for this situation (perhaps if the object at the end of the chain wasn't a gadget with a relationship, but a value for a property of widget), just so I can have a better understanding of how more complicated predicates and subqueries work.

Comment: I have tested the predicate `"@"ANY bar.widgets.gadget == %@"`. It worked and produced the expected result.

Comment: I had similar problem as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697355/nspredicate-to-get-childrens-childrens

Comment: For anyone looking how to generate an `NSPredicate` for multiple to-many relationships, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22102471/470225). You have to use a `SUBQUERY`.