# NSPredicate to get children's children's

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, fetch

[image: Data Model]

I want to fetch all the treatments, that are children of this List object.

I am not sure if it can be done.

I have a TableView showing all the patients of a list. Each patient can have many treatments.

I have a reference to the current list, and want to use that to somehow find the childrens children.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a fetch request for the "Treatment" entity with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ofPatient.ofList = %@", currentList]
```

using the *inverse relationships* from "Treatment" -> "Patient" -> "List".

Comment: Thank you 100% right, I tried everything but that, its so obvious when you see the answer. My last attempt before coming to stackoverflow was this, NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", self.selectedList.listPatients]; Thanks again!