# NSPredicate to many like a <----->> b----->c

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have **entities: Language, Proper and Answer**.

model look like `Language{A:name(NSString), R:propers(NSSet)} --->> Proper{A:name(NSString), R:answer(Answer)} ---> Answer{A:answer(NSString)}`

So, i got NSDictionary with params: `{@"key1", @"value1"}, {@"key2", @"value2"}... i`

I need create **NSPredicate** from this dictionary to get all **Languages** where `propers.name = key[i]` and `propers.answer.answer = value[i]` from my NSDictionary.

Example:

`C++`

`level : high`

`try/catch : yes`

`typization : static`

`Java`

`level : high`

`try/catch : yes`

`typization : dynamic`

`NSDictionary : {level : hight}, {try/catch : yes}, {typization : dynamic}`

//make and set NSPredicate to array controller
//array controller arrangedObjects will return Java

Sorry for bad grammar :/

**Update**
**After 2 weeks of sleepless nights and work on expert system teacher took a laboratory without checking it. Kill me please. Thanks a lot to all of you.**

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697355/nspredicate-to-get-childrens-childrens

Comment: Can you explain better what *"all suited A entities"* are? Perhaps with some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just guessing what you want to do so here is a code:

```
- (NSPredicate *)constructPredicateWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [dictionary allKeys];
    NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *key in allKeys) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(B, $B, $B.key = %@ && $B.C.value = %@).@count > 0", key, [dictionary valueForKey:key]];
        [predicates addObject:predicate];
    }


    //not quite sure what you need so I am guessing

    NSPredicate *finalAndPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates]; //if you want all the predicates to be concatenated with and '&&' - logical expression - so all of the subqueries have to be correct
    NSPredicate *finalOrPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates]; //if you want all the predicates to be concatenated with or '||' - logical expression - so any of the subqueries has to be correct

    return finalOrPredicate; //return the needed predicate
}
```

Comment: Using this code my program is finally no longer throws an exception :) And it looks like it is working properly! Very big thanks and have great future! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need from SUBQUERY. Something like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"B.key = %@ AND SUBQUERY(B, $B, $B.C.value = %@).@count > 0", key, value];
```

The SUBQUERY iterates through the objects and you can also have nested SUBQUERYs if you have more than one to-many relationships.

You can use and "ANY ..." but it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: This does not compile, and `"B.key = @"key1"` or `$B.C.value = @"value"` is incorrect predicate syntax. Also `"B.key = ...` does not make sense because  A -->> B is a to-many relationship. - It is probably difficult to answer the question without more information what the intended result exactly is.

Comment: This is pseudocode. In this case You need: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"B.key = %@ AND SUBQUERY(B, $B, $B.C.value = %@).@count > 0]", key, value];`