# Core Data predicate : unimplemented SQL generation for predicate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

Basically I got 3 entities in my data model : Brand, Model and Trim.

- A brand has a one-to-many relationship with Model called "models". (one brand have multiple models but a model has only one brand)
- A model has a many-to-many relationship with Trim called "trims". (a model can have multiple trims, and a trim can have multiple models)

Having an array of trims objects, I would like to get all the brands having a model which "contains" at least one trim contained inside this array.

So here is my predicate for the fetch request :

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Brand"];    
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY models.trims IN %@", arrayOfTrims];
```

And here is the error I'm getting :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (ANY models.trims IN {<Trim: 0x8e60340> (entity: Trim; id: 0x8e62f10 <x-coredata://BCD28560-AED5-4409-9A35-1925001773E6/Trim/p8>
```

I'm kinda new to Core Data and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Hope someone can help,

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"ANY" in a Core Data predicate works only for a *single* to-many relationship.
Since your query involves *two* to-many relationships, you have to use a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(models, $m, ANY $m.trims IN %@).@count > 0",
    arrayOfTrims];
```

Comment: @MartinR, I typically visit stackoverflow with an assumption I'll find an answer. With this particular problem, I had the lowest of expectations given limited CoreData predicate success in the past. With that backdrop, I was shocked to see your solution solve my problem. Thank you for taking the time to post it.

Comment: Does the Subquery work with Fetched Property, if its an array?

Answer (score 25):

This exception is also raised if one of the predicates uses a column (i.e. field) name that does not exist. Totally misleading error message...

Comment: Nailed it. Thx.

Comment: Yes. I had a spelling mistake .

Answer (score 5):

When you use a predicate in a CoreData operation, the predicate gets translated into SQL.  That translation is not possible for all NSPredicate operations, you've hit one that isn't.  My suggestion would be something along the lines of:

```
NSMutableArray* predicates = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSString* trim in arrayOfTrims)
{
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN models.trims", trim]];
}
NSPredicate*    predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```

Comment: Just tried out and got almost the same error :
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (<Trim: 0x1700a6c00> (entity: Trim; ... IN models.trims)'

Answer (score 5):

The keyword `IN` can be used but you cannot apply ANY at the same time as that does not make sense when you turn it into SQL.

The predicate you are most likely looking for is:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"models.trims IN %@", arrayOfTrims];
```

But that isn't going to work in this case either because you are going across a relationship.  So what you need to do is reverse the whole thing:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Model"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trims in %@", arrayOfTrims]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *modelArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (!modelArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
NSArray parentObjectArray = [modelArray valueForKey:@"${PARENT_RELATIONSHIP_NAME}"];
```

Basically you are fetching the child objects to satisfy your `ANY` and then using KVC to retrieve the parent objects that you care about.

Comment: This will result in an array that may contain duplicate `Model` objects. also it might be better to add the key-path `model.brand` as a relationship for prefetching or performance will be dreadful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because I made a silly mistake and didn't have the argument in the right data type.

I was trying to do:

`let firstPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", firstNameField.stringValue)`

and forgot to put the ".stringValue."