# multiple to-many keys not allowed here

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have this DB entities:
[image]

I want to get the categories that have devices installed.

should be something like:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(String(Category), inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
let request = NSFetchRequest()
request.entity = entity
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY brands.devices.isInstalled == true")
```

But it doesnt work, `error: 'multiple to-many keys not allowed here'`

Thanks

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101233/core-data-predicate-unimplemented-sql-generation-for-predicate/22102471#22102471 ?

Comment: I tried it in this way, but it doesnt work either:
    SUBQUERY(brands, $brand, $brand.devices.isInstalled == true)