# NSPredicate for Nested Relationships (many to many) iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I've been struggling for several hours and thought I'd reach out to SO.  In my app's data model, I have an entity, `SubCategory`, which has many `CreatedTask`, and each `CreatedTask` can have many `User`:

[image]

Say I have an User entity variable, called `userObject`.

I want to fetch all `SubCategories`, where `tasks.assignees` has `userObject`.  How do I do this?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
let userFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SubCategory")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN tasks.assignees", userObject)
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

However I am generating a nasty error:

> unimplemented SQL generation for predicate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full Error Output:
[image]

Comment: have you seen this question/answer that might help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101233/core-data-predicate-unimplemented-sql-generation-for-predicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to yan's help I was able to figure it out, just had to place the user object into an array.

```
let users: [User] = [userObject]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(tasks, $m, ANY $m.assignees IN %@).@count > 0", users)
```

Comment: Great!  Happy Coding!