# Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object

Tags: swift, core-data, nsorderedset

When I perform segue I pass all seasons from a selected show to the next ViewController.

```
class ShowsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Request Items with type = Movie
        let request: NSFetchRequest<TelevisionShow> = TelevisionShow.fetchRequest()
        allShows = try! CoreDataStack.context.fetch(request)
        allShows = allShows.sorted(by: { $0.title! <  $1.title! })
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Create a variable that you want to send based on the destination view controller

        selectedShow = allShows[indexPath.item]

        // This will perform the segue and pre-load the variable for you to use
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSeasonsViewController", sender: self)

    }
```

If I try a fetch request with NSPredicate, I get crash. (2019-02-04 11:10:48.766456+0100 TV[16295:659978] `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.')`

```
class SeasonsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request: NSFetchRequest<Season> = Season.fetchRequest()
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(televisionShow, $m, ANY $m.seasons IN %@).@count > 0",(pTelevisionShow?.seasons)!)

        allSeasons = try! CoreDataStack.context.fetch(request)
        allSeasons = allSeasons.sorted(by: { $0.number! <  $1.number! })
    }

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var pTelevisionShow: TelevisionShow?
}
```

[image: xcdatamodeld]
The problem is that first time I'm selecting a tvshow and perform segue, it works well, if I go back and choose another tvshow, it throws that error.

+

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

pTelevisionShow?.seasons is NSOrderedSet

[image: xcdatamodeld]
The solution:

```
allSeasons = pTelevisionShow?.seasons!.sorted(by: { ($0 as! Season).number! < ($1 as! Season).number! }) as! [Season]
```

Comment: Have you looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101233/core-data-predicate-unimplemented-sql-generation-for-predicate

Comment: Looks like your predicate is returning a single object rather than a collection of objects

Comment: Cant really find what may be the problem, It returns right number of seasons for first time, then if I go back and perform segue again: ")}).@count > 0); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects: YES; )
2019-02-04 10:09:14.910457+0100 TV[12970:579035] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.'"

Comment: Update your question with relevant code (remove anything not related to your current problem). Also, put an exception breakpoint and share with us the line of code at which it gives that error.

Comment: @twixQ Does the other tv show have seasons information available?

Comment: Yes, when it performs segue for first time, it displays all seasons well, the problem occurs just if I'm going back and selecting another tvshow, or the same again.

Comment: @twixQ Hold on, `pTelevisionShow?.seasons` will give references to the seasons anyways, so why do you need `Season.fetchRequest()` at all?

Comment: `allSeasons = pTelevisionShow?.seasons.sorted(by: { $0.number! <  $1.number! })` should work without any `fetchRequest`

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for your help and patience, it works now!

Comment: @twixQ Coool, I've posted an answer. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.')

Looks like your predicate is returning a single object rather than a collection of objects.

So your predicate logic `NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(televisionShow, $m, ANY $m.seasons IN %@).@count > 0",(pTelevisionShow?.seasons)!)` is returning a single element for some reason.

However, in your case, since you're passing `pTelevisionShow` forward, your structure already has reference to the required `seasons` dataset and can be directly accessed, so you don't need a `fetchRequest` on `Season` again.

---

Remove the following code:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Season> = Season.fetchRequest()
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(televisionShow, $m, ANY $m.seasons IN %@).@count > 0",(pTelevisionShow?.seasons)!)
```

Change and keep:

```
allSeasons = pTelevisionShow?.seasons.sorted(by: { $0.number! < $1.number! })
```